# How to add 2 groups with rows inside Group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I see that I can create a group and then add rows inside the group but the problem is I need the first added row's cell to lie under the group value

example:

```
CompanyGroup
MarketGroup
```

so I have those 2 groups and in for example the company group, I've added a row with the "Inside Group" option.  It adds the row but I end up with this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
- Company -
-         --------------------------------------------------
-         - value  -  value   -  value   - value  -   value
------------------------------------------------------------
```

but I need the row of values to lie flush UNDER Company, left aligned for this company group:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
- Company
- ----------------------------------------------------------
- value  -  value   -  value   - value  -   value
------------------------------------------------------------
```

So you end up with results like this:

```
CompanyA
someField1  somefield2  someField3

CompanyB
someField1  someField2  someField3
```

..and so on

not sure how to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question correctly but if I am:

When you click a cell in your group you will see something similar to (much simpler then in your example) the following in the footer:

[image]

The area you want to be playing around with to get this right is the 'totals'. For example:

[image]

Alternatively, if this isn't right (as I could be wrong) - Is it possible that you simply need to merge the cells of your leading row?